# How should I draw a moderator's attention to someone who's commited to an Area 51 proposal with an inappropriate name?

Tags: support, flags, area-51

I noticed a proposal where there was a committed user whose name was around the lines of "f*** the people who proposed this". This person hasn't commented or anything, so I can't flag one of their posts, but their name is still front and center on the proposal's main page. What can I do to draw moderator attention to this person? There aren't any flag/report buttons on their profile / commitment box.

Comment: I think it's also good to note that Area 51 is monitored frequently by the CM team, so they'd catch onto something suspicious right away.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I did, and the user has been removed.

Comment: Flag yourself (some post of yours) with "other" and explain in detail always works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using the `contact us` link at the bottom of the page. Include a link to the profile and submission, and I'm confident it will be handled quickly by the Community Team.

Answer (score 3):

Area 51 has flags. Below the proposal description, there is an option to flag.

Comment: I thought that was for if the proposal itself was inappropriate

Comment: @Drew You can still use them to get moderator attention though. The issue doesn't have to be about the proposal.

Comment: Ah, alright. I had thought flagging that instead of the user (even though that can't be done) to get their attention would be the flag equivalent of an off-topic post or something. Good to know it's fine to use that.

Comment: @Drew Oh no. Custom Moderator flags can be used for any issue. If you ever need the attention of a moderator, just use a flag anywhere, and describe the situation :)